# GridView With Adjustable Row Heights

Tags: android, gridview

Hi i have a requirement of developing the gridview with adjustable row heights same as flipkart and paytm apps.but i am unable to find out the way.please help me on this.my requirement is as below
[image]

Please give me some example

Comment: maybe look on google for staggered gridview android.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RecyclerView` and `StaggeredGridLayoutmanager`:

https://github.com/Mobeyosoft/Recyclerview-Sample